# Как закрыть все окна Toplevel?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Есть программа и она сворачивается в трей. Встретился с проблемой - основное окно сворачивается в трей, а окна `Toplevel` остаются открыты. Можно ли их все одним махом закрыть?

Comment: Можно запоминать открытые окна в списке, при сворачивании в трей основного 
окна их тоже скрывать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно пройтись по всем дочерним виджетам, там будут и топлевелы, и попробовать каждый свернуть. Тот который сворачевается — топлевел, если ошибка — проигнорировать:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
...
def minimize_all():
    root.wm_state('iconic')
    for i in root.winfo_children():
        try:
            i.wm_state('iconic') # We suppose that `i` (each child of the root) is toplevel and try to minimize it...
        except:
            pass # But sometime it may be a button or a label or something so we can't and we just ignore such exceptions.

...
```

Comment: Стоит перевести комментарии на русский язык или дать объяснение на русском вне блока кода

Comment: @dIm0n Объяснение сейчас дам. А комменты в коде я считаю надо писать по-английски.

Comment: @VictorVosMottor комментарии в коде для международного сообщества (например, в проекте выложенном на github) имеет смысл писать на английском.  Комментарии в коде, выложенном конкретно для русскоязычного сообщества (ruSO) лучше писать на русском.